# C# UWP - Does DLL size matter?

Tags: c#, xamarin, dll, uwp, size

For example I have dll that has 5 mb size and contains 5 classes. I reference the dll to my project and I only use 1 class from that dll. so when I release the project, is the dll only wrap 1 class or 5 classes? Thanks. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, an external library is being "wrapped" completely.

If you would only take a part of the library, you can miss some key features required by the internal workings of the one class you use.

With regards,
John

Comment: .Net native actually trims the code to only what is being used AFAIK.